# How to stick notification icon with menu toggle on small screens and right on large screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to stick notification submenu to toggle menu in small screens and stick to right on small screens like the following

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Abount</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-list">
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown-animate="" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
        <span class="label label-danger">11</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

But unfortunately it does not work. Please help me how could I do it?

Comment: Can you add a mockup of what you'd like it to look like on a small screen and a large screen.  Also, make sure you're adding jquery.js before bootstrap.js. Also, are you intending the notification submenu to act as a dropdown?  If so, where are it's children item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the notification always visible, you could add them to the `nav-header` like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed">...</button>

  <div class="nav navbar-brand pull-right">
      <a href="#" >
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
        <span class="label label-danger">11</span>
      </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

```css
.notifications.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" >
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
              data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target=".navbar-collapse" >
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="nav navbar-brand pull-right notifications">
          <a href="#" >
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
            <span class="label label-danger">11</span>
          </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Abount</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  </nav>
```

Comment: And the last couple of questions: how can I add one more button to the left and is it correct to use second .navbar-brand class name for this purpose?

Comment: You could use another `.navbar-brand` if you'd like.  It just applies some important formatting so that the object has the correct padding an height to fit inside of the navbar and look natural.  It's not entirely semantic and their might be a more appropriate class name, but this'll work.